# What is the best way to overcome or get rid of pitru dosh

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, astrology, vedic-gods, manuscripts

What is pitru dosha according to scriptures and How to get rid of the pitru dosha?

Answer (score 2):

Pithru Dosah is a karmic penalty that one suffers after having practised black magic or their ancestors who have used to it to harm others life. It may aso be due to not respecting your father/ father's ancestors in your previous births.

I am guessing by your name that you might be a south Indian

You must know the story of Luv Kusa.One day the Aswamedha Yagna was conducted by Lord Rama at Ayodhya and the horse was running away and reached this place, which is presently called Koyembedu. Earlier it was called Kosai. The horse has to be traced and brought back to the place where Yagna was started. But these two children of Rama kept the horse and firmly resisted Lord Rama's battalion. Finally Lakshman also came and he was also defeated. Finally Lord Rama had to enter into the battle and his sons were preparing. Fortunately, Saint Valmiki made the children realise that they are going to fight against their own father and vice versa. So the children had been affected by Pitru Dosha for going against ones own father So they performed a penance to cure from the Curse. Lord Shiva appeared as a linga before them (Syambhu) and have cured them from the curse. So the temple is said to cure people from Pitru Dosha.

Other remedies for Pitru Dosha

> By completing “Trapandi Shradh”.
> •By completing the Shraad on the date on which our ancestors were expired.
> • By giving water to the Banyan tree.
> • By offering water to our Pitras for the 15 days during the Shraad or on the date of their death.
> • One should offer food to Brahmins on every “Amavasya”.
> • By donating food items on every “Amavasya” and “Poornima” in some temple or other religious places.
> These were the remedies by which a person suffering from “Pitra Dosh” can get rid of this Dosh. In the same way, if someone wants to get rid of Pitra dosh then he/she should do the Shraad with his full respect so as to get blessings of his/her Pitras.

I believe lord Shiva will help you

Kurungaleeswarar Temple- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurungaleeswarar_Temple

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Pitrudosha (the curse of the father in previous birth) is formed when certain planetary combinations are found in the horoscope. I am not going into the details of the planetary combinations that lead to Pitrudosha. However, the result of the Pitrudosha is the lack of a male progeny. Here are the remedies.

> To get deliverance from the curse of the father the remedial measures are-
> (1) Performance of Shraddha at Gaya,
> (2) to feed ten thousand, one thousand or hundred Brahmins as one can afford,
> (3) Kanyadana (to perform the marriage of a girl)
> (4) giving a cow to charity.
> By observing these remedial measures the person concerned
> becomes free from the curse and the family lineage is prolonged
> by the birth of sons, grandsons etc.

**- Brihat Parasara Hora Shastra, Chapter 83, Verses 31-33.**